# How to implement quotation replies on Commerce orders by multiple users?

Tags: 7, commerce

Commerce order will have 0 price when being placed, Once the order is placed all the users of specific role will get notification(this is working) and should be able to reply to that order(I am making a custom module and view for this) with their own price for that order. There will be multiple fields data to reply like price, qty, destination, etc.

I don't want to create a new order or order revision.I want to be able to somehow add all quotation data to that order for each user.I have seen some quotation like modules but they do not do what I need.

My question is where to save all those fields and data?How to relate it with that order?

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to allow those users of a specific role to flag orders.

When configuring the (non-global) flag(s), attach appropriate fields to them, as described in [Attaching fields to flags](https://www.drupal.org/node/917576). These fields could perfectly match with the "*multiple fields data to reply like price, qty, destination, etc.*" (as in your question).

If needed, use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to add all sorts of additional (custom) logic to the mix, eg:

- only allow such flagging to happen within selected timeframes.
- send (eMail) notifications to appropriate users.
- perform field level validations (whatever may seem to be needed).
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am looking into this. I am able to flag the order with fields but how do i apply flag for each line item in the order? There doesn't seem to be any option for that.

Comment: @TejasVaidya : your question contains "*... should be able to reply to that order...*", which is also what my answer is about. If you're looking for something at the level of each line item, then that seems a different question to me, no? Or did I miss anything in your current question? PS: maybe you should post some type of followup question (if appropriate with a reference to this question)?

Comment: Yes, You are right I made a little mistake and missed that part while asking the question. Anyway i was able to add data for each line item using field collection in the same flag,so it worked out well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TejasVaidya : merci for the accept!